# Is there a way in webpack watch mode to display on screen the timestamp when webpack last updated the build?

Tags: webpack, webpack-hmr

Sometimes while running webpack in watch mode and editing source files I am not sure whether webpack has packed my changes or not.

Is there a way to print a timestamp to the console each time webpack updates the bundle?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add a custom plugin like:

```
config.plugins.push(new function() {
    this.apply = (compiler) => {
        compiler.hooks.done.tap("Log On Done Plugin", () => {
            console.log(("\n[" + new Date().toLocaleString() + "]") + " Begin a new compilation.\n");
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 9):

The answer of datou3600 is awesome, but why not to be better?

Adding a little delay:

1. The text is placed at the end
2. A screen blinks noticeable to an eye

Here is the code:

```
config.plugins.push(function(){
    this.plugin('done', function(stats) {
        setTimeout(
            () => {
                console.log(('\n[' + new Date().toLocaleString() + ']') + ' --- DONE.\n');
            },
            100
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Install [webpack-watch-time-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-watch-time-plugin).

It displays the time when watcher rebuild happens.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with webpack 5.

Answer (score 4):

Just an update as

```
DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
```

you can do it like this:

```
class WatchTimerPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap('Watch Timer Plugin', (stats) => {
      console.log(('\n[' + new Date().toLocaleString() + ']') + ' --- DONE.\n');
    });
  }
}

module.exports = WatchTimerPlugin;
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you wanted to use the timestamp programmatically - e.g. for debugging, or to ensure that remote synchronization of your latest build worked properly - you could also use [`webpack.DefinePlugin.runtimeValue`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#runtime-values-via-runtimevalue):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    BUILDTIME: webpack.DefinePlugin.runtimeValue(Date.now, true)
})
```

This would always give you the latest build time through the constant `BUILDTIME`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem also may be solved without any WebPack modification by the terminal app. For instance, in the iTerm there is a setting "Show Timestamps".

[image]
The result looks like that:
[image]